# Javascript - How to export a function and use it inside the same model.js file?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am from php oop develoment and I know that there are many ways to create classes in JS. I need a support from a JS developer to solve this issue.

This is the scenario:
I'm creating an AWS lambda function with nodeJS. I have a model called here as `model1`. Inside this model I want to export some functions. Some others will be used internally (like a private method in oop php).

```
model1.js

'use strict'
const { var1 } = require('../utils/...')
const { var2 } = require('../utils/...')
...

exports.fn1 = async (par1) => { ... }
exports.fn2 = async (par2) => { ... }
exports.fn3 = async (par3) => { //This could be used outside and inside this file
let someVar = await someMysqlstatement ...
}
exports.fn4 = async (par1) => { //Would like to use fn3 here
let someVar2 await f3(par3)
}
```

I want to know if it is possible to export fn3 and make it available in the `module1.js` at the same time. If this is not a good approach what it would be?

Comment: FWIW, now that it's well-bedded-in, I'd use ESM: https://pastebin.com/Mk86sxSQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the functions first

```
const fn3 = async (par3) => { ... }
```

and then export the ones you want to export at the end of the file:

```
module.exports = {
   fn3,
   ...
}
```

Note that above export statement will *replace* the `module.exports` object. Instead of replacing it, you can add new properties to it as shown below:

```
exports.fn3 = fn3;
exports.fn4 = fn4;
...
```

Separating the function definition and the export statement will allow you to use the function `fn3` inside the `module1.js` file.

---

Also note that nodeJS also supports [ES modules](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/esm.html).

With ES modules, you can export your functions as named exports like:

```
export const fn3 = async (par3) => { ... }
```

and if you want to use any of the exported function in the same file, just use its name.

Comment: FWIW, I recommend not *replacing* the `exports` object like that, there's one already provided, just assign to it: `const fn3 = exports.fn3 = async ()...`. (Although actually, here in 2021, I recommend using ESM rather than CJS... :-) )